# How to draw a dynamic circle in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, geometry, xcode6.1

How to draw a dynamic circle in Objective-C

I have to draw 2 circles first outer circle radius is fixed shown in figure filled with green Color (A).

The other circle is dynamic based on some radius(B).

How can I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249675/dynamically-redraw-re-sized-circle-in-iphone?lq=1

Comment: This is like 2 maybe 4 lines of code. There are built in Apis to draw circles. Didn't you think to try them first?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass an `UIView` and then override its `drawRect` method. Inside it use some `NSBezierPath`s and `NSColor` settings to make your drawings.

`drawRect:`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:

Cocoa drawings
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH201-SW1

Bezier paths
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html

Colors
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Color/Color.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH205-BAJDFIFE

Answer (score -1):

This might help you,

Download sketch from apple. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Sketch

[see more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-BBCHFJJG)

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354610/create-a-colored-bubble-circle-programmatically-in-objectivec-and-cocoa/354646#354646)